# inserting objects of a custom class in a set with a unique identity which is related to the object's element

Tags: c++, object, data-structures, set

I have a set of my custom object. The custom Class is Path.There is a Node object in each path and the last node indicates the last node of the path.Moreover; Each Node object has a unique ID which is NodeID. I want to store a collection of these paths in a set, and I want to assign the last node ID of each path as its unique identity.

```
struct Path {

    Node rootNode;
    Node lastNode;
    queue<Node> pathNode;
    path(Node root) {
        this->rootNode=root;
        this->lastNode=root;
        pathNode.push(root);
    }

    void addNodeToPaht(Node node) {

        pathNode.push(node);
        this->lastNode=node;

    }
    Node getLastNode() {
        return lastNode;
    } };
```

here is the definition of my set:

```
set<Path> visitedPath;
```

I mean I don't want to have  two paths with the same last node. However I want to store 
the whole path object in the set, not the only last node_Id. How can I do it?

Comment: A set is always a collection of unique object, and using `std::set` the unicity is defined by default using `std::less<T>`.

Comment: You could get this to work with a set, but it might make more sense to use a map from Node -> Path

Comment: How is `SSNode` related to `Node`?

Comment: they are same, it was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `operator<()` function in `Path` and implement it by using the ID of the last node.

```
bool operator<(Path const& rhs) const
{
   return (this->getLastNode().getNodeID() < rhs.getLastNode().getNodeID());
}
```

Comment: I used something like this  struct identication{
  bool operator ()(const pathStruct& first, const pathStruct& second ){
    
    return (first.lastNode.getNodeID()!=second.lastNode.getNodeID());
  }
};

Comment: Since you are trying to create a `set` of `Path`s,  you need a function that can do a comparison of `Path`s. The `operator<()` function is just one way to do it.